# How to convert a scalar index to a 2 dimensional index in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, adjacency-matrix

Let's say we have a set of N nodes that can be coupled, as in a complex network, and we don't care of the direction of the link (so the link between 1 and 2 is the same as 2 and 1).

I want to use a numpy one-dimensional array to represent the state of each link. The state takes values in {1,0}, where 1 means that the link exists. The array, let's call it "state", should be N*(N-1)/2 long, I suppose (auto-loops are excluded).

In such a context, how could I index properly all the links that start in node a, or the links that end in node b? If we call the array "states", I would to say that state[i] = state of a link that starts in node a, or that end in node j. Is there a way, possibly an efficient way, to do this? If we have N=10 nodes, the first 8 entries correspond to links starting from node 1 and ending in nodes 2,3,4,...,10, but I can't find a general way to express this. Thanks.

P.s.: I know that a 2D matrix may be more useful, but for my purposes I would like to solve the issue keeping the states in a 1D array.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the intro tour.  "please solve my design problem" is too broad and under-defined to qualify as a Stack Overflow question.  You have already described the data structure you want; it seems that the present sticking point is the programming acumen to write the supporting code for your desired functionality.  That comes from practice; when you have a good attempt at the code you want, *that* could make a good Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

The index for pair of nodes (a,b) can be computed using a variable base determined by the number of preceding elements for the smaller of the two node IDs.  Adding the larger one to that base gives the proper index:

You can make a function to get the state index from a pair of node identifiers (zero based) like this:

```
def indexOf(a,b,N=10):
    return indexOf(b,a,N) if a>b else N*a-a*(a+1)//2+b
```

produces indexes as requested:

```
for a in range(10):
    print([indexOf(a,b) for b in range(10)])

[0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
[1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[2, 11, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[3, 12, 20, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
[4, 13, 21, 28, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[5, 14, 22, 29, 35, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
[6, 15, 23, 30, 36, 41, 45, 46, 47, 48]
[7, 16, 24, 31, 37, 42, 46, 49, 50, 51]
[8, 17, 25, 32, 38, 43, 47, 50, 52, 53]
[9, 18, 26, 33, 39, 44, 48, 51, 53, 54]

allPairs = [ (a,b) for a in range(10) for b in range(a,10) ]
print( sorted(allPairs,key=lambda ab:indexOf(*ab) ) )
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 9)]
```

*Note that this allocates entries for node links to themselves*

The drawback of that indexing model is that it requires that the number of nodes (N) be known in advance and supplied on every call.

A more generic approach would be to index the flat list differently based on a progression that does not require having a predetermined value for N.  Every pair will always be at the same index no matter the total number of nodes:

```
def indexOf(a,b):
    return indexOf(b,a) if a<b else a*(a+1)//2+b
```

it can be reversed (to get the node pair at a given index) like this:

```
def unindex(X):
    b = int( ((8*X+1)**0.5-1)/2 )
    a = X - b*(b+1)//2
    return a,b
```

The indexes are not in the same order but the function doesn't need to know N:

```
for a in range(10):
    print([indexOf(a,b) for b in range(10)])

[0,  1,  3,  6,  10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
[1,  2,  4,  7,  11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46]
[3,  4,  5,  8,  12, 17, 23, 30, 38, 47]
[6,  7,  8,  9,  13, 18, 24, 31, 39, 48]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 25, 32, 40, 49]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 26, 33, 41, 50]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 34, 42, 51]
[28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 43, 52]
[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 53]
[45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]

print( [unindex(x) for x in range(N*(N+1)//2) ])
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (0, 5), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (0, 6), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (0, 8), (1, 8), (2, 8), (3, 8), (4, 8), (5, 8), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 8), (0, 9), (1, 9), (2, 9), (3, 9), (4, 9), (5, 9), (6, 9), (7, 9), (8, 9), (9, 9)]
```

Using numpy, if you have an array of node pairs, you can get their corresponding state indexes by writing the function (2nd version) like this:

```
import numpy as np

def indexOf(ab):
    a,b = np.max(ab,axis=-1),np.min(ab,axis=-1)
    return a*(a+1)//2 + b
```

output:

```
N = 10

states = np.arange(N*(N+1)//2)%2        # some random node links

pairs = np.array( [[1,3],[2,4],[7,2]] ) # array of node pairs

connected= states[indexOf(pairs)]       # indirection to states

print(states)
# [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
print(indexOf(pairs))
# [ 7 12 30]
print(connected)
# [1 0 0]
```

if you use the first version of the function, you will need to pass the number of nodes on every call:

```
def indexOf(ab,N=10):
    a,b = np.min(ab,axis=-1),np.max(ab,axis=-1)
    return N*a-a*(a+1)//2+b

connected= states[indexOf(pairs,N=10)]
```